# Evaluate the sum of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of following series:

$\frac{1}{2.3}+\frac{1}{4.5}+\frac{1}{6.7}+...$

After some arrangement, I got below step:

$\frac{1}{2.3}+\frac{1}{4.5}+\frac{1}{6.7}+...=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k+2}- \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k+3} $

Now, I have no idea how to find this difference of two series. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand $$\ln(1+x)$$

Comment: The series on the left converges, and the two series on the right do not, so that approach may not be useful. Your series is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$. Now have you seen something like this before?

Comment: @lab battacharjee $ 1-\log 2$

Comment: how after some (re-)arrangement you reached the summation difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2k(2k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=1-\ln2.$$
The last step follows from $\ln (1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ by setting $x=-1$.

Comment: I got the answer before your post. Thanks

Comment: How did you move from the telescoping expression to the alternating one?

Comment: @zz20s The $k$th term in the first expression is the sum of $2k$th and $(2k+1)$th terms in the second (e.g. $\frac12-\frac13=\frac{(-1)^2}2 +\frac{(-1)^3}3$).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @zz20s I converted each terms appear in sum to factorial form.

Answer (score 0):

The general term for the above series is 1/(2r)(2r+1).
This can be broken into partial fractions. Write the numerator as 2r+1-2r and thus this general term can be written as 1/(2r+1) - 1/(2r).
sum the terms from r=1 to n, and then take the answer in a limit n approaching infinity.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your posts.